# Implement close function on keypress in c++ builder

Tags: c++, winforms, c++builder, keypress, vcl

How do I implement Close (or exit) function when the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key is pressed in a form application in C++ builder?

Also, note that the form will have a number of components; it can't be only an empty form.
I tried to use this code but it doesn't work every time I press <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormKeyPress(TObject *Sender, System::WideChar &Key) {
if (Key == VK_ESCAPE) {
    this->Close();
}}
```

The code above doesn't work because focus is not always on the form and, if you have more components like EditBox, you have to disable `VK_ESCAPE` on every event and reference the desired function (which is, of course, a weak solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `TForm::KeyPreview` property and `TForm::OnKeyPress` event is the best approach, but an alternativve would be to put a hidden `TButton` on the form and set its `Cancel` property to true, then you can call `Close()` in its `OnClick` event.

Answer (score 3):

Set the KeyPreview property of the Form to true. This way, keyboard events occur on the form, before the active control.